# What is the phpBB code For paragraph Tag and New Line

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I want to pass paragraph with new line.

Sending Variable -

```
"topic_body": "[p]This is a paragraph.[/p][p]This is a paragraph.[/p] [p]This is paragraph.[/p]"
```

Receiving Result is:

> [p]This is a paragraph.[/p][p]This is a paragraph.[/p] [p]This is paragraph.[/p]

What I am expecting:

> This is a paragraph.
>
> This is a paragraph.
>
> This is a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one, you would need to use a custom bbCode, you can create your own under the posting tab in your ACP like this:

Example

```
[p]{TEXT}[/p]
```

HTML replacement

```
<div style="margin:5px 0;">{TEXT}</div>
```

Help line

```
[p]This is a paragraph[/p]
```